# Show arrays arranged in a specific format

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array in JavaScript:

```
myArray = ["lu9","lu10","lu11","ma9","ma10","ma11","mi9","mi10","mi11"];
```

Then, I need to display the values ​​(for example in an alert) but must be arranged as follows:

```
"lu9,ma9,mi9,lu10,ma10,mi10,lu11,ma11,mi11"
```

How I can do this?

Comment: So you want to sort them first numerically, then alphabetically?

Comment: I don't think I have a full solution, but to try to break the problem down: This way of sorting numerically doesn't fit perfectly with most alphanumeric sorting, so you may need to make your own "comparator function" that will divide the letter/number portions, and make a comparison based on both.

Comment: Will it always be a two-letter string followed by numbers, or is that changeable?

Comment: Will the numbers ever exceed the range of 0 to 99?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var myArray = ["lu9", "lu10", "lu11", "ma9", "ma10", "ma11", "mi9", "mi10", "mi11"];

function myResult(myArray) {
    myArray = myArray.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
        var reg = /\d+/ //A regex to extract the numerical part
        var num = 2 * (+a.match(reg) - +b.match(reg)) //Put a weight of 2 on the numerical value
        var str = a > b ? 1 : a < b ? -1 : 0 //The strings value with a single weight
        return num + str //add them and we have a positive or negative value with a correct weight on the numerical part
    })
    return "" + myArray

}

console.log (myResult(myArray)) //"lu9,ma9,mi9,lu10,ma10,mi10,lu11,ma11,mi11"
```

Heres a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Glutamat/8tQJV/)

Comment: No need for regex. you can use the sort function. **use it!** that's why it's there for

Comment: @RoyiNamir Could you elaborate that? I don't exactly get what you mean with it.

Comment: you use the sort function and also use regex. for what ?  you can only use the sort function without regex. much efficient. see my edit.

Comment: @RoyiNamir to extract the number part from the string *(who knows if it couldn't be 3 or 4 digit suffix)*, to be able to put a weight on it in realation to the string part. Who cares about performance, the readability is quite more important in such a case, its not that the OP is in the need to exhaustively run this millions of times.

Comment: Oh and could anyone explain the downvote? =) If theres something i could improve i would like to do so

Comment: it was me , forget it. rollbacking. if the OP needs dynamics  , he should use yours/zirak. if only 2 , then mine. I got tired of this question. +1.

Comment: @RoyiNamir No problem =) And don't understand me wrong, i didn't wanted to be offensive, i just expected a bit more quality in a 20+ks' Answer

Answer (score 3):

Each item in your list has two parts: The leading mishmash of characters (mi, ma, lu) and a numerical suffix. To properly sort, we have to take both into account.

```
array.sort(function sorter (a, b) {
    var re = /^(\D+)(\d+)$/,
        left = re.exec(a),
        right = re.exec(b);

    if (left[1] === right[1]) {
        return Number(left[2]) - Number(right[2]);
    }

    return left[1] < right[1] ? -1 : 1;
});
```

Let's say `a = lu9` and `b = lu10`:

```
1. left = ['lu9', 'lu', '9']
2. right = ['lu10', 'lu', '10']
3. left[1] === right[1]
   1. Number(left[2]) = 9
   2. Number(right[2]) = 10
   3. return 9 - 10 (negative number, a before b)
```

Now if our input is `a = lu9` and `b = mi4`:

```
1. left = ['lu9', 'lu', '9']
2. right = ['mi4', 'mi', '4']
3. left[1] !== right[1]
   1. left[1] < right[1] = true
   2. return -1
```

Comment: no need for regex. the sort function can do it without regex. you need to sort by number and then letters so sort it with number and then letters.

Comment: I am using `array.sort`, that doesn't mean regepx aren't a good complement. With them, scenarios outside of OPs specific scenario can be solved (what if his prefixes change from 2 characters to 1, to 4, to 15?) And in here, I don't sort by numbers and then letters - I sort by letters and then numbers, which is more logical (since it's the way the strings are built).

Answer (score 2):

We need to sort **first by number and then by letters**.
no need for regex here.

We will use padding:

```
so ma11 will be 0011ma
and mi11 will be 0011mi
and ma11 will be 0011ma

(and mi9 will be 0009mi , the padding helps 11 to be bigger then 2 as string)
```

so sorting it now - will yield the right result.

```
var a = ["ma9", "ma10", "ma11", "mi9", "mi10", "mi11", "lu9", "lu10", "lu11"]
a.sort(function (a, b)
{
        return   calc(a) > calc(b);
});

function calc(x)
{
    return ("0000" + x.slice(2)).slice(-4) + x.slice(0,2);
}
```

result :

```
    ["ma9", "ma10", "ma11", "mi9", "mi10", "mi11", "lu9", "lu10", "lu11"]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var myArray = ["lu9","lu10","lu11","ma9","ma10","ma11","mi9","mi10","mi11"];

var derp = function(a, b) {
    a = a.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '', a);
    b = b.replace(/[^0-9]+/g, '', b);
    return a < b;
}

myArray.sort(derp);
```

Comment: This applies to your's too: What about `var myArray=["ma11","mi11","ma11"]` shouldn't the correct output be `[ma11,ma11,mi11]` instead of `["ma11", "mi11", "ma11"]` ?

Comment: Instead of `[^0-9]` you can do `\D` which stands for "not a digit"